Android Native App Install Banner Not Working in 2024
We have a react website that has an associated iOS and Android app. I set up a smart app banner for iOS and that was a breeze, but I'm having issues getting the Android App Banner to display.
TL;DR I need to know if the banner is provided by Google Chrome, or if I have to provide one and listen for the beforeinstallprompt event and have a custom banner / button that fires the prompt() callback?
Based on how I know the iOS app banner works, and following a ton of other stack overflow posts, and following along with this guide (that's supposedly from 2023), it seems like the banner is provided by Chrome, and there's nothing more I need to do other than:

Provide the specific manifest in the public folder
Provide icons (also in public folder)
Add the <link .../> to the index.html
Serve all of the above from https

I've checked the manifest in the desktop chrome dev tools and only get a few warnings about full sized screenshots for Richer PWA install ui which I think is to be expected. The PWA installs fine on Android from the three dot menu.
Part of the issue is that it looks like Google has removed the #bypass-app-banner-engagement-checks that everyone mentions you can turn on to skip the engagement checks. So I've had to make changes, then visit the site 2 days in a row to try to trigger the banner with no luck, then make changes and try again.
Here's the scrubbed manifest:
{
  "short_name": "App Name",
  "name": "App Name",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "36x36_banner-icon.png",
      "sizes": "36x36",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "48x48_banner-icon.png",
      "sizes": "48x48",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "72x72_banner-icon.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "96x96_banner-icon.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "144x144_banner-icon.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "192x192_banner-icon.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "512x512_banner-icon.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "prefer_related_applications": true,
  "related_applications": [
    {
      "platform": "play",
      "id": "the.google.play.store.id",
      "url": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=the.google.play.store.id"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone"
}


Tried advice from all older stack overflow posts (most current is over a year old now). Have not seen the banner display at all.

Related chromium bugs: https://issues.chromium.org/issues?q=bypass-app-banner-engagement-checks and specifically: https://issues.chromium.org/issues/40737338 and https://issues.chromium.org/issues/40284228 Further discussion/related issues: https://issues.chromium.org/issues?q=customfield1222907:%22UI%3EBrowser%3EWebAppInstalls%3EDesktop%22

Your manifest looks like it has one minor problem. From my own personal experience, the start_url property needs to be a complete URL, e.g., "https://{domain}", not just ".".
Regardless, the prompt won't display without a user gesture, such as a button click. So you need to

Create a button on your page and style it with display:none.
Add the "beforeinstallprompt" window event handler. The handler should set your button to be visible and save the event to a deferredEvent variable in a parent (or global) scope.
Add the "click" button event handler. The handler should invoke deferredEvent.prompt(), and deferredEvent.userChoice.then().

Finally, and also from my own experience, you don't need the start_url or display properties at all, except when you are testing on your local desktop Chrome browser. Android Chrome doesn't care about those if you have a real Android app in the Play Store.
You can find the official documentation at https://developer.chrome.com/blog/app-install-banners-native/
